# Is there any way to remotely disable a command block?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make a cool thing in minecraft. and I need to disable a certain command block with a flick of a switch. Is there any command that I can put in a command block the will disable command blocks? I don't want to disable all of them, just one. Anything I can do about this?

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the command block to chain and conditional and chaining it after a repeating command block that checks if a lever is flicked, the command should look something like this:
`/execute if block <coordinates to the lever> minecraft:lever[powered=true]`

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to disable a repeating command block, by toggling it from "always active" to "needs redstone". That can be done by setting its "`auto`" NBT tag to `false`, for example like this:

```
/data merge block 12 34 56 {auto:0}
```